# How can I prevent null from showing up?

Tags: java, if-statement, null

Sorry I'm a beginner so the answer may be obvious but I'm trying to make a code where it will tell you your horoscope based on your dob and based off that tell you your daily, monthly, and yearly horoscope.

```
import java.io.*;
public class MysticLady {

static String zodiacSign = "";
static String dailyDescript = "";
private static java.util.Scanner myScanner;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader keyIn = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Welcome user to the world of the mystic truths!");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("My name is Mirela and will be telling you all about you...");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("But first, what is your name?");

    myScanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    String name = myScanner.nextLine(); 

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println( name + ", what a lovely name");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Well " + name + ", I need to first know your date of birth");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Keep in mind that by knowing this I will be able to tell you certain things");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("We currently have daily, monthly, and yearly horoscopes available");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Now first tell me what month were you born (1-12)");

    int month = Integer.parseInt(keyIn.readLine());

    System.out.println("Now what day were you born?");

    int day = Integer.parseInt(keyIn.readLine());

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    System.out.println(name + ", the galaxy is telling me that your zodiac sign is " + MysticHoroscope1.getZodiacSign());

    System.out.println("Now that we know your sign, would you like to know your daily, monthyly, or yearly horoscope?");
    String horotype = myScanner.nextLine();
    {
    if (horotype.equalsIgnoreCase("daily"))
        {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Today is May 11, 2017");
        System.out.println("Your horoscope for today is...");
        System.out.println("" + MysticHoroscope1.getDailyDescript());
    if (horotype.equalsIgnoreCase("monthly"))
        {System.out.println("");
    if (horotype.equalsIgnoreCase("yearly"))        
        {System.out.println("");
    }   
}}}}}


public class MysticHoroscope1 { 
private static String zodiacSign;

int month;
int day;
    public MysticHoroscope1(int m, int d)
    {

    int month = m;
    int day = d;
    switch (month)
    {
    case 1 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 20)
    setZodiacSign("Capricorn");
    else if (day > 20 && day < 32)
    setZodiacSign("Aquarius");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;

    case 2 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 19)
    setZodiacSign("Aquarius");
    else if (day > 19 && day < 30)
    setZodiacSign("Pisces");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;

    case 3 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 20)
    setZodiacSign("Pisces");
    else if (day > 20 && day < 32)
    setZodiacSign("Aries");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;
    case 4 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 20)
    setZodiacSign("Aries");
    else if (day > 20 && day < 31)
    setZodiacSign("Taurus");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;
    case 5 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 21)
    setZodiacSign("Taurus");
    else if (day > 21 && day < 32)
    setZodiacSign("Gemini");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;
    case 6 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 21)
    setZodiacSign("Gemini");
    else if (day > 21 && day < 31)
    setZodiacSign("cancer");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;
    case 7 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 22)
    setZodiacSign("Cancer");
    else if (day > 22 && day < 32)
    setZodiacSign("Leo");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;

    case 8 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 21)
    setZodiacSign("Leo");
    else if (day > 21 && day < 32)
    setZodiacSign("Virgo");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;

    case 9 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 23)
    setZodiacSign("Virgo");
    else if (day > 23 && day < 31)
    setZodiacSign("Libra");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;

    case 10 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 23)
    setZodiacSign("Libra");
    else if (day > 23 && day < 32)
    setZodiacSign("Scorpio");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;

    case 11 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 22)
    setZodiacSign("Scorpio");
    else if (day > 22 && day < 31)
    setZodiacSign("Sagittarius");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;
    case 12 :
    if (day > 0 && day <= 22)
    setZodiacSign("Sagittarius");
    else if (day > 22 && day < 32)
    setZodiacSign("Capricorn");
    else
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    break;
    default :
    setZodiacSign("Sorry, that's not a valid date");
    }

    }

public void MysticHoroscope(int month2, int day2) {
    }

public static String getZodiacSign() {
    return zodiacSign;
}

public static void setZodiacSign(String zodiacSign) {
    MysticHoroscope1.zodiacSign = zodiacSign;
}
    public static String dailyDescript;
    {
        if (zodiacSign.equals("Capricorn"))     
            setDailyDescript("There are many ways to journey through life,\nbut you will only know the path you choose to travel.\nThis is a wonderful day to expose yourself to new art,\nespecially if it's from a different culture.\nTurn the dial on your radio or television to a foreign-language broadcast.\nLeave it there for a few minutes. You'll be surprised how intriguing you find it.\nEvery now and then, it's wise to travel down an unfamiliar side street.");
        if (zodiacSign.equals("Aquarius"));
            setDailyDescript("Stand up for yourself and watch how quickly people back down.\nToday, you will be able to talk to absolutely anyone--even the folks who usually intimidate you.\nIt's a great day to ask for a raise, try to get some face time with the big boss, or ask someone out on a date.\nYou'll give off an unmistakable air of confidence, which might be a bit stronger than what you actually feel.\nThis level of boldness could open up some very important doors for you.");
        if (zodiacSign.equals("Pisces"));
            setDailyDescript("Finding a balance between what you want and what is best for everyone involved is important today.\nBefore making any decisions, you have to factor in other people's feelings and goals.\nThis could be difficult, because you can't exactly read minds.\nLuckily, your intuition is strong, and you can sense what people want.\nDon't bend too far backward to accommodate them, though.\nJust let them know you considered their feelings -- that's plenty of incentive.");
    }
    public static String getDailyDescript() {
    return dailyDescript;
    }
    private static void setDailyDescript(String dailyDescript) {
    MysticHoroscope1.dailyDescript = dailyDescript;
}



}
```

Everything "works" except for the actual answer.

```
name, the galaxy is telling me that your zodiac sign is null
Now that we know your sign, would you like to know your daily, monthyly, or yearly horoscope?
daily
Today is May 11, 2017
Your horoscope for today is...
null
```

Comment: Well... you never set `zodiacSign` or `dailyDescript`, so they're null. Also, your formatting is messy and makes the code difficult to read.

Comment: yeah, I'm not surprised

Answer (score 1):

Issues include:

- You're setting the class variable `dailyDescript` in an instance initializer. You want an instance member. Remove `static` from the declaration.
- That initializer gets called before `setZodiacSign()` is called, and then never again. You'll want to either move that code so that it can be called after setZodiacSign(), or initialize the zodiac sign and description in the constructor.
- When you move that code to allow calling it from `setZodiacSign()`, you'll need to cover all the zodiac signs in that code, and ideally, provide a final `else` that handles bad values in some way.
- You have global variables in the class containing `main()` that are neither necessary nor used.

Comment: Thank you, sorry to continue asking but how can I change this?

Comment: Which issue are you asking about? Note that each of the points above but the last describes how to address the problem, and the last can be addressed by removing the unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify your code as little as possible for the answer (even if everything in my body strive against it).

**Your class `MysticLady`**

You have:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);

System.out.println(name + ", the galaxy is telling me that your zodiac sign is " + MysticHoroscope1.getZodiacSign());
```

Problem:

1. The class `MysticHoroscope1` contains the logic for the horoscopy in the constructor, but that one is never called.

**Solution.** Just add one line in between:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);

new MysticHoroscope1(month, day);

System.out.println(name + ", the galaxy is telling me that your zodiac sign is " + MysticHoroscope1.getZodiacSign());
```

The class `MysticHoroscope1` contains

**Next class `MysticHoroscope1`**

You have:

```
public static void setZodiacSign(String zodiacSign) {
    MysticHoroscope1.zodiacSign = zodiacSign;
}
public static String dailyDescript;
{
    if (zodiacSign.equals("Capricorn"))
    setDailyDescript("There are many ways to journey through life,\nbut you will only know the path you choose to travel.\nThis is a wonderful day to expose yourself to new art,\nespecially if it's from a different culture.\nTurn the dial on your radio or television to a foreign-language broadcast.\nLeave it there for a few minutes. You'll be surprised how intriguing you find it.\nEvery now and then, it's wise to travel down an unfamiliar side street.");
    if (zodiacSign.equals("Aquarius"));
    setDailyDescript("Stand up for yourself and watch how quickly people back down.\nToday, you will be able to talk to absolutely anyone--even the folks who usually intimidate you.\nIt's a great day to ask for a raise, try to get some face time with the big boss, or ask someone out on a date.\nYou'll give off an unmistakable air of confidence, which might be a bit stronger than what you actually feel.\nThis level of boldness could open up some very important doors for you.");
    if (zodiacSign.equals("Pisces"));
    setDailyDescript("Finding a balance between what you want and what is best for everyone involved is important today.\nBefore making any decisions, you have to factor in other people's feelings and goals.\nThis could be difficult, because you can't exactly read minds.\nLuckily, your intuition is strong, and you can sense what people want.\nDon't bend too far backward to accommodate them, though.\nJust let them know you considered their feelings -- that's plenty of incentive.");
}
```

Problems:

1. The description for the horoscope is initialized in an anonymous block when the class is instantiated and depends on the `zodiacSign`. But the `zodiacSign` is initialized in the constructor (actually after the anonymous block is evaluated)
2. The `if`-statements ends with colons

**Solution.** Make this:

```
public static void setZodiacSign(String zodiacSign) {
    MysticHoroscope1.zodiacSign = zodiacSign;

    if (zodiacSign.equals("Capricorn"))
        setDailyDescript("There are many ways to journey through life,\nbut you will only know the path you choose to travel.\nThis is a wonderful day to expose yourself to new art,\nespecially if it's from a different culture.\nTurn the dial on your radio or television to a foreign-language broadcast.\nLeave it there for a few minutes. You'll be surprised how intriguing you find it.\nEvery now and then, it's wise to travel down an unfamiliar side street.");
    if (zodiacSign.equals("Aquarius"))
        setDailyDescript("Stand up for yourself and watch how quickly people back down.\nToday, you will be able to talk to absolutely anyone--even the folks who usually intimidate you.\nIt's a great day to ask for a raise, try to get some face time with the big boss, or ask someone out on a date.\nYou'll give off an unmistakable air of confidence, which might be a bit stronger than what you actually feel.\nThis level of boldness could open up some very important doors for you.");
    if (zodiacSign.equals("Pisces"))
        setDailyDescript("Finding a balance between what you want and what is best for everyone involved is important today.\nBefore making any decisions, you have to factor in other people's feelings and goals.\nThis could be difficult, because you can't exactly read minds.\nLuckily, your intuition is strong, and you can sense what people want.\nDon't bend too far backward to accommodate them, though.\nJust let them know you considered their feelings -- that's plenty of incentive.");
}
public static String dailyDescript;
```

I strongly encourage you to rethink your design.

Answer (score -1):

`zodiacSign` is holding the value of `null` in your program, so that's what it is printing. I would suggest you to check for null to eliminate that issue.

Your `null` check should look like this:Previously it was the same only not commented

```
if (zodiacSign!=null && !zodiacSign.isEmpty) {
    //do your stuff here...
} else {
    //what you want to do if get null zodiacSign
}
```

this is not an issue, but i suggest trying to format your code for better readability as it is staggered.